# Ranking a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been banging my head against this for a few days now and can't find a solution.

I have an array that looks like the following.

```
var myArr = [
[1, 10],
[0, 9],
[0, 8],
[0, 11],
[0, 12]
];
```

The data is a list of items for sale, the first element is a 0 if its not mine and a 1 for my item, the second element is the price.

From this I need to return the rank of the one with a 1 in it against the others [3/5] so I need to sort it by the second element then get the rank of the first element.

I've been trying to use this code to sort it

```
myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Then this to find the rank

```
    function getIndexOfK(arr, k) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
            if (index > -1) {
                return [i, index];
            }
        }
    }

    var needle = 1;
    var result = getIndexOfK(competitorsArr, needle);
    console.log('The value #' + needle + ' is located at array[' + result[0] + '][' + result[1] + '].');
```

But it is returning this every time?

The value #1 is located at array[0][0].

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Many Thanks,

Richard

Comment: If you need to sort it by the second element why are you doing `a[0]` and not `a[1]`? (and the same with `b[0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I need to sort it by the second element then get the rank of the first element.

Yep, but, in your code:

```
myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
});
```

you're sorting by the *first* element, not the second. Fix that, and it works fine:

```js
var myArr = [
  [1, 10],
  [0, 9],
  [0, 8],
  [0, 11],
  [0, 12]
];

myArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});


function getIndexOfK(arr, k) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
    if (index > -1) {
      return [i, index];
    }
  }
}
console.log(getIndexOfK(myArr, 1));
```

You could reduce the time complexity by identifying the price of your item, and then iterating over the array and checking how many items are cheaper, `O(N)`, no sorting required:

```js
var myArr = [
  [1, 10],
  [0, 9],
  [0, 8],
  [0, 11],
  [0, 12]
];
const myPrice = myArr.find(([owner]) => owner === 1)[1];
const numCheaperThanMine = myArr.reduce(
  (a, [owner, price]) => (
    price < myPrice && owner !== 1
    ? ++a
    : a
  ),
  0
);
console.log(numCheaperThanMine);
```

Comment: Yup. That said... `getIndexOfK` is not very efficient, and can do the wrong thing (in case there's an item with price equal to `needle`). `myArr.findIndex(x => x[0] == needle)` is faster, shorter and correct.